# fire jquery-ui.toggleSwitch.js toggle switch at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I found a ToggleSwitch plugin that uses Jquery UI library but I can't seem to find a way to toggle the switch after init at runtime.

The plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/taitems/UX-Lab/blob/master/ToggleSwitch/js/jquery-ui.toggleSwitch.js)

With Jquery slider, one can simply force slider change through values option, ie:

```
$("#slider").slider('values', 0,100);
```

The configuration options include:

```
$(".selector").toggleSwitch({
  highlight: true, // default
  width: 25, // default
  change: function(e) {
  console.log("i changed my value")
 } // default: null
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="on-off" class="ui-toggle-switch">
   <option selected="selected">ON</option>
   <option>OFF</option>
</select>
```

Create toggle switch on it:

```
$("#on-off").toggleSwitch();
```

To toggle - call "click" on label for option "off" (index = 1):

```
$("div.ui-toggle-switch").find("label").eq(1).click();
```

eq(1) here is index of option value (OFF). For ON it would be eq(0).
Here's fiddle with timeout to force "OFF" from code: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZSuw/

Comment: that is very nice, I figured out another way by modifying the plugin but your way is just so much cleaner. thank you